# Discussion replies via E-mail creates new thread

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, discussion-board, incoming-email

I have a Community site which contains a Discussion List, I have configured In-coming emails for this list and subscribed the alerts for the same list. When i send a email to the configured list email id for first time it creates a new Discussion post as expected, but after that if i try sending email to same post for reply via mail received from alert it creates a new Post insted of reply to discussion. Has anyone faced similiar situation ? please help me to fix this.

Comment: are you replying the email or sending the email in new windows? when you send the email, is that include the "Re:" in the subject line?

Comment: I am replying the mail, I have created an alert for the Discussion list so when user creates a post I get alert of new topic being posted, I am replying to the same alert email which i get for the topic, yes it has RE: and topic in subject line  this is my subject when I reply "RE: Discussions List - Test Discussion"

Comment: I have tried detecting few things by mapping iDiscussion list to my drive i came to know that for every Discussion it creates a folder in root eg:If i post Discussion with Subject "Test Discussion" it will create folder with same name in root now when i reply to mail it would create another folder "Test Discussion 2129" in this manner so it creates a new discussion though the subject of this newly formed discussion remains the same as "Test Discussion"

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Today i have noticed a very unusual behaviour of SP, when i send by e-mail it creates a new thread in discussion list, to this mail if I send a reply i.e same subject with "RE:" in it, this would post reply as expected to the topic created by mail but when you try to do this for a existing thread it would create a new thread instead of reply

Answer (score 1):

You can just add "RE: " for the subject line to have it as reply for the existing discussion subject